# Who sets the price and provides the quoted price values for stocks?

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges, markets, quotes, price

I somewhat understand that the price of stocks is determined by the market, but who exactly changes those prices that we see listed on Yahoo! Finance for example?

If I own a share in a company listed in NASDAQ, does NASDAQ update the price based on how much people are willing to buy it at or sell it at? How does NASDAQ know what price I'm willing to sell or buy at?

Comment: Related: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/6809/does-an-executed-limit-order-imply-a-spot-price

Comment: @NickC's answer is nice but don't forget to look at the role of [market makers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Market_maker) in the operations of the NYSE, AMEX and NASDAQ etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The "price" is the **price of the last transaction** that actually took place.

According to [Motley Fool wiki](http://wiki.fool.com/Share_price):

> A stock price is determined by what was last paid for it. During market hours (usually weekdays from 9:30AM-4:00PM eastern), a heavily traded issue will see its price change several times per second. A stock's price is, for many purposes, considered unchanged outside of market hours.

Roughly speaking, a transaction is executed when an offer to buy matches an offer to sell.

These offers are listed in the **Order Book** for a stock (Example: [GOOG at Yahoo Finance](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ecn?s=GOOG+Order+Book)).  This is actively updated during trading hours.

This lists all the currently active **buy** ("bid") and **sell** ("ask") orders for a stock, and looks like this:
[image]

You'll notice that the stock price (again, the **last sale price**) will (usually*) be between the highest bid and the lowest ask price.

---

<sup>***** Exception: When all the buy or sell prices have moved down or up, but no trades have executed yet.</sup>