# How prices in stock market changes in accordance with demand and supply

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-exchanges, stock-valuation, shorting-securities

Let's assume there is a listed company x. Currently it has 100 shares issued to trade in free float market. Current price of stock is let say 10. Now please let me know if I purchase one share of company x at the market price of 10. How it will effect the stock price. And please add and exemplify some other scenarios whichever you find good to explain more. For more information let say promoters of the company holds 100 shares with them like 50% of the company is with promoters and the other half is with people who invest or trade in that company. If I've missed to tell or assume any other vital info. needed please assume it yourself while mentioning it.
I want to go deep down into the concept of demand and supply. How technically it happens.
Thank You

Comment: This question was [asked yesterday](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/139741/i-want-to-know-by-an-example-how-prices-in-stock-market-changes) and was closed.  This one should therefore be closed as well.

Comment: There's an explanation at [How is stock price determined?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/35686/how-is-stock-price-determined) and [many other related questions on the site](https://money.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bstocks%5d%20price%20is%3aq) you can search through.

Comment: I think this question is interesting because so many of the ideas in the question have basically nothing to do with market price setting.